# "ls -l" doesn't show symlinks source paths

Tags: zsh, symlink

Before I reinstalled MacOS, `ls -l` showed symlinks with their source path. Now `ls -l` shows symlinks as regular files - without the source path.

How can I make it show the source path?

I'm on a clean MacOS installation with ZSH and a basic `.zshrc` file.

Here's an image where `etc` is showed with it's source:

[image]

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/  Also, you have asked about the behaviour of `ls -l` but have shown the behaviour of `ll`.  Show the behaviour of the command that you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, please show us the output of `/bin/ls -l`. If that works, show us the output of `type ll` and `type ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible `ls` is reporting the file system correctly but instead your folders are hardlinked instead.

However without seeing the output from `ls` that you are *now* seeing (rather than what you are *expecting* to see), any answer here would be largely speculative.

> @JdeBP: Also, you have asked about the behaviour of `ls -l` but have shown the behaviour of `ll`. Show the behaviour of the command that you are asking about

`ll` is usually just an alias for `ls -l` (for example, defined in the users `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: "usually" is not good enough.  I've seen enough variations on these over the years to not take what they may expand to for granted, and to not take for granted that `ls` _itself_ is not a shell function/alias.

Comment: You're right, it was a hard link, all makes sense now. Thank you so much for the thoughtful response!